# Continuous loop using threading

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, timer, multiprocessing

I am somewhat new to python. I have been trying to find the answer to this coding question for some time. I have a function set up to run on a threading timer. This allows it to execute every second while my other code is running. I would like this function to simply execute continuously, that is every time it is done executing it starts over, rather than on a timer. The reason for this is that due to a changing delay in a stepper motor the function takes different amounts of time run.

Comment: Can you show the code you've written? It will be easier to provide guidance if we can see what you've already tried.

Comment: if you want the function to execute continuously why not just write the function so that it starts itself over? then just start it in a new thread once, and it will continuously run in that thread?

Comment: @vik: if you mean call itself recursively, then you hit recursion depth limit, i.e. ``RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded``

Comment: i see why it seems like i meant recursion, I meant more like write it so that it will just inf loop or something and repeat the task over and over again, rather than continually have something externally call it over and over again. I can't see why that would be preferable to just having the function loop if you want to get as close to no time delay between the function calls.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
from threading import Thread

def f():
    print('hello')

while True:
    t = Thread(target=f)
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

Or maybe this, which shows the concurrent paths of execution (for production, remove `sleep()` calls, of course):

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def g():
    print('hello')
    sleep(1)

def f():
    while True: g()

Thread(target=f).start()
sleep(1)
print('other code here')
```

Comment: Probably he's looking for a solution without using an infinite loop.